# Como enviar una imagen a un archivo php

Tags: php, javascript, html, imagen

Tengo un problema para mandar una imagen a un archivo php.

Para empezar tengo una pagina con un `<form>` donde envio distintos datos a mi archivo php para luego subirlos a una base de datos. Con esto no tengo ningún problema.

El problema surge cuando quiero ademas, enviar una imagen que obtengo mediante un script a el mismo archivo php. No se me ocurre como ponerlo en un input y después obtenerlo con el método POST.

Espero haber sido claro con la consulta. Desde ya muchas gracias y les dejo un poco de mi codigo a continuacion.

**Script Para obtener la imagen:**

```
$(document).on('click', "#testImg" , function() {

    html2canvas($('#map'), {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            uploadMap(img,"uploads/mapas");
            $('<img>', {
                src: img
            }).appendTo($('.tst2'));
        }
    });
});
```

**Input donde quiero guardar la imagen para obtenerla con POST en el archivo php**

```
<input type="hidden" name="mapRoute" value="">
```

Comment: No entiendo bien de donde es que sale esta imagen, pero si podes conseguir los bytes, podes codificarlos en base64 y mandarlos como una variable de post.

Comment: ya en esta variable `var img = canvas.toDataURL();` tienes el codigo en base64 si mal no recuerdo, ahora solo tienes que agregarlo a tu input `$("input[name=mapRoute]").val(img)`y enviarla con el resto del formulario. En PHP la decodificas y la subes a tu server

Comment: En lugar de enviar un data uri a la base de datos, puedes enviar un url: cuando subes la imagen, recuperas el url de la imagen y lo guardas a la base de datos.